# Add Comma Function in JavaScript is Too Greedy

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I modify the function below to make it stop adding commas once we hit the decimal marker?

```
addCommas = function(number) {
    if(number === undefined) {
        return '';
    }

    while(/(\d+)(\d{3})/.test(number.toString())) {
        number = number.toString().replace(/(\d+)(\d{3})/, '$1'+','+'$2');
    }

    return number;
}

addCommas(0.123456); // Outputs 0.123,456, should output 0.123456
```

Comment: set a boolean flag to `true` when `.` was encountered.

Comment: If this isn't just an exercise for you to learn something, I'd probably use numeral.js:  http://numeraljs.com/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to print a number with commas as thousands separators in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2901102/1048572)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My method is to split the number into fractional and integer parts...

```js
addCommas = function(number) 
{
    if (number === undefined)
        return '';
    var parts = number.toString().split(".");
    parts[0] = parts[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    return parts.join(".");
}

document.write( addCommas(0.123456) + "<br />" );
document.write( addCommas(123456.123456) + "<br />" );
document.write( addCommas(123456) + "<br />" );
```

Comment: +1 for doing what I was doing but in a much simpler and cleaner way.

Answer (score 4):

Just add `^[^.]*` to the front of the pattern:

```
addCommas = function(number) {
    if(number === undefined) {
        return '';
    }

    while(/^[^.]*(\d+)(\d{3})/.test(number.toString())) {
        number = number.toString().replace(/(\d+)(\d{3})/, '$1'+','+'$2');
    }

    return number;
}
```

You only have to do that for the `.test()` call.

Answer (score 1):

I would break the string in two prior to using the regular expression. Such as:

```
RenanCommas = function(number) {
    if(number === undefined) {
        return '';
    }

    var parts = (number + "").split(".");
    var integerPart = parts[0];
    var decimalPart = parts.length > 1 ? parts[1] : "0";

    while(/(\d+)(\d{3})/.test(integerPart.toString())) {
        integerPart = integerPart.replace(/(\d+)(\d{3})/, '$1'+','+'$2');
    }

    return integerPart + "." + decimalPart;
}
```

Notice that you could also have `decimalPart` as an empty string. In that case, you could check whether or not it is empty before using it. If you use an empty string instead of `"0"`, the last line would be something like:

```
    return integerPart + (decimalPart ? ("." + decimalPart) : "");
```

And when you run it:

```
RenanCommas(12121241243.1123131232); // outputs "12,121,241,243.112312"
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be working:

```
addCommas = function(number) {
   return number.replace(/(\.\d+$)|(?!^)(?=(?:\d{3})+(?=\.|$))/g, function($0, $1) {
       return ($1)?$1:','; });
}
```

**Examples:**

```
addCommas('0.123456');
"0.123456"
addCommas('987654.123456');
"987,654.123456"
addCommas('987654321');
"987,654,321"
```